# android backgroun does not change

Tags: android, background

I want my program to have the background color `#222222`. My graphical editor in eclipse shows me that it has this color but when I start the app on my device it has still a white background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#222222" >


</LinearLayout>
```

in my PlaylistFragment.java :

```
//This is the fragment which uses this layout
public class PlaylistFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_playlist, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should set background for fragment layout. Is this LinearLayout fragment or main activity?

Comment: @VladimirKulyk fragment